# Ajax insert mysql.

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть такой скрипт:

```
$(function() {
    $(".msg-post_input").click(function() {
        var text = $("#post_new_txt").val();
        var dataString = 'message='+ text;
        if(text=='') {

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "messages/postmsg.php?id=<?=$myrow2[id]?>&hash=<?=$hash?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                    $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
                    document.getElementById('post_new_txt').value='';
                    document.getElementById('post_new_txt').focus();
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

И так заношу в бд:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
    $hash = $_GET['hash'];
}

if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $new_message    = $_POST['message'];
    $user_one       = $_POST['from_id'];
    $user_two       = $_POST['from_id_to'];
    mysql_query(
        "INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','$hash','$user_one','$user_two','$new_message',now(),'0')"
    ) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query(
        "UPDATE message_group SET date_group=now() WHERE hash=$hash"
    ) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Проблема в том, что вот `$user_one` айди мой заносится в бд, а айди другого пользователя почему-то не заносит, или заносит мой же. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Давайте задом на перёд пройдём, смотрим php: `$user_two` берётся из поля "from_id_to" POST-запроса.

Теперь идём в JS. Там в POST'е передаётся содержание `dataString` (строка `data: dataString`). А что вы в эту переменную пишете ранее? только строку "message="+содержание поля формы с id `#post_new_txt`.

Так что неоткуда взяться ни первому, ни второму id.

Comment: На ваш вопрос ответили выше, еще советую изучить [материал][1]. У вас там данные никак не валидируются, посему возможно провести sql-injection.
  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php